# Postfix and dovecot configuration problem

Tags: ubuntu, postfix, email-server, dovecot

i faced a problem in configure Postfix and Dovecot as Mailing System for my VPS on Ubuntu 9.04 for Virtual Users.
where i can't send or receive any mails.

from the errors i got : Fatal: postmaster_address setting not given

kindly find the below configurations:

### Postfix main.cf

```
smtpd_banner = $myhostname ESMTP $mail_name MailMin
biff = no
# appending .domain is the MUA's job.
append_dot_mydomain = no

# Uncomment the next line to generate "delayed mail" warnings
#delay_warning_time = 4h

readme_directory = no

# ---------------------- TLS PART START ----------------------
smtp_use_tls = yes
smtpd_tls_received_header = yes
smtpd_tls_mandatory_protocols = SSLv3, TLSv1
smtpd_tls_mandatory_ciphers = medium, high
smtpd_tls_auth_only = yes
tls_random_source = dev:/dev/urandom
smtpd_tls_cert_file = /etc/postfix/smtpd.cert
smtpd_tls_key_file = /etc/postfix/smtpd.key
smtpd_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtpd_scache
smtp_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtp_scache
# ---------------------- TLS PART END ----------------------

myhostname = mobithought.com
alias_maps = hash:/etc/aliases
alias_database = hash:/etc/aliases
myorigin = /etc/mailname
mydestination =
relayhost =
mynetworks = 127.0.0.0/8 [::ffff:127.0.0.0]/104 [::1]/128
home_mailbox = Maildir/
mailbox_command = /usr/lib/dovecot/deliver -c /etc/dovecot/dovecot-postfix.conf -n -m "${EXTENSION}"
mailbox_size_limit = 0
recipient_delimiter = +
inet_interfaces = all
inet_protocols = all
message_size_limit = 30720000

# ---------------------- SASL PART START ----------------------
smtpd_sasl_auth_enable = yes
smtpd_sasl_type = dovecot
smtpd_sasl_path = private/dovecot-auth
smtpd_sasl_authenticated_header = yes
smtpd_sasl_security_options = noanonymous
smtpd_sasl_local_domain = $myhostname
broken_sasl_auth_clients = yes
# ---------------------- SASL PART END ----------------------

smtpd_recipient_restrictions = permit_mynetworks, permit_sasl_authenticated,reject_unauth_destination, reject_unknown_sender_domain, reject_unknown_recipient_domain, reject_unauth_pipelining
smtpd_data_restrictions = reject_unauth_pipelining, reject_multi_recipient_bounce, permit
smtpd_sender_restrictions = reject_unknown_sender_domain

virtual_minimum_uid = 5000
virtual_uid_maps = static:5000
virtual_gid_maps = static:8
virtual_mailbox_base = /home/vmail
virtual_transport = dovecot
virtual_create_maildirsize = yes
virtual_maildir_extended = yes
dovecot_destination_recipient_limit = 1
virtual_mailbox_domains = proxy:mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql-domains.cf
virtual_mailbox_maps = proxy:mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql-mailboxes.cf
virtual_alias_maps = proxy:mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql-forwards.cf
virtual_mailbox_limit = proxy:mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql-mailboxes-limits.cf
virtual_alias_domains =

proxy_read_maps = $local_recipient_maps $mydestination $virtual_alias_maps $virtual_alias_domains $virtual_mailbox_maps $virtual_mailbox_domains $relay_recipient_maps $relay_domains $canonical_maps $sender_canonical_maps $recipient_canonical_maps $relocated_maps $transport_maps $mynetworks $virtual_mailbox_limit_maps
```

### Dovecot-Postfix Config

```
protocols = imap pop3 imaps pop3s
disable_plaintext_auth = no

#log_path = /var/log/mail/dovecot-error.log
#info_log_path = /var/log/mail/dovecot-info.log

log_timestamp = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S "

##
## SSL settings
##

# IP or host address where to listen in for SSL connections. Remember to also
# add imaps and/or pop3s to protocols setting. Defaults to same as "listen"
# setting if not specified.
#ssl_listen =

# Disable SSL/TLS support. <doc/wiki/SSL>
ssl_disable = no

# PEM encoded X.509 SSL/TLS certificate and private key. They're opened before
# dropping root privileges, so keep the key file unreadable by anyone but
# root.
ssl_cert_file = /etc/ssl/certs/ssl-mail.pem
ssl_key_file = /etc/ssl/private/ssl-mail.key

# If key file is password protected, give the password here. Alternatively
# give it when starting dovecot with -p parameter. Since this file is often
# world-readable, you may want to place this setting instead to a different
# root owned 0600 file by using !include_try <path>.
#ssl_key_password =

# File containing trusted SSL certificate authorities. Set this only if you
# intend to use ssl_verify_client_cert=yes. The CAfile should contain the
# CA-certificate(s) followed by the matching CRL(s).
#ssl_ca_file =

# Request client to send a certificate. If you also want to require it, set
# ssl_require_client_cert=yes in auth section.
#ssl_verify_client_cert = no

# Which field from certificate to use for username. commonName and
# x500UniqueIdentifier are the usual choices. You'll also need to set
# ssl_username_from_cert=yes.
#ssl_cert_username_field = commonName

# How often to regenerate the SSL parameters file. Generation is quite CPU
# intensive operation. The value is in hours, 0 disables regeneration
# entirely.
#ssl_parameters_regenerate = 168

# SSL ciphers to use
ssl_cipher_list = ALL:!LOW:!SSLv2:ALL:!aNULL:!ADH:!eNULL:!EXP:RC4+RSA:+HIGH:+MEDIUM

# Show protocol level SSL errors.
#verbose_ssl = no

##
## Login processes
##

# <doc/wiki/LoginProcess.txt>

# Directory where authentication process places authentication UNIX sockets
# which login needs to be able to connect to. The sockets are created when
# running as root, so you don't have to worry about permissions. Note that
# everything in this directory is deleted when Dovecot is started.
#login_dir = /var/run/dovecot/login

# chroot login process to the login_dir. Only reason not to do this is if you
# wish to run the whole Dovecot without roots. <doc/wiki/Rootless.txt>
#login_chroot = yes

# User to use for the login process. Create a completely new user for this,
# and don't use it anywhere else. The user must also belong to a group where
# only it has access, it's used to control access for authentication process.
# Note that this user is NOT used to access mails. <doc/wiki/UserIds.txt>
#login_user = dovecot

# Set max. process size in megabytes. If you don't use
# login_process_per_connection you might need to grow this.
#login_process_size = 64

# Should each login be processed in it's own process (yes), or should one
# login process be allowed to process multiple connections (no)? Yes is more
# secure, espcially with SSL/TLS enabled. No is faster since there's no need
# to create processes all the time.
#login_process_per_connection = yes

# Number of login processes to keep for listening new connections.
#login_processes_count = 3

# Maximum number of login processes to create. The listening process count
# usually stays at login_processes_count, but when multiple users start logging
# in at the same time more extra processes are created. To prevent fork-bombing
# we check only once in a second if new processes should be created - if all
# of them are used at the time, we double their amount until the limit set by
# this setting is reached.
#login_max_processes_count = 128

# Maximum number of connections allowed per each login process. This setting
# is used only if login_process_per_connection=no. Once the limit is reached,
# the process notifies master so that it can create a new login process.
#login_max_connections = 256

# Greeting message for clients.
#login_greeting = Dovecot ready.

# Space-separated list of elements we want to log. The elements which have
# a non-empty variable value are joined together to form a comma-separated
# string.
#login_log_format_elements = user=<%u> method=%m rip=%r lip=%l %c

# Login log format. %$ contains login_log_format_elements string, %s contains
# the data we want to log.
#login_log_format = %$: %s

##
## Mailbox locations and namespaces
##

# Location for users' mailboxes. This is the same as the old default_mail_env
# setting. The default is empty, which means that Dovecot tries to find the
# mailboxes automatically. This won't work if the user doesn't have any mail
# yet, so you should explicitly tell Dovecot the full location.
#
# If you're using mbox, giving a path to the INBOX file (eg. /var/mail/%u)
# isn't enough. You'll also need to tell Dovecot where the other mailboxes are
# kept. This is called the "root mail directory", and it must be the first
# path given in the mail_location setting.
#
# There are a few special variables you can use, eg.:
#
# %u - username
# %n - user part in user@domain, same as %u if there's no domain
# %d - domain part in user@domain, empty if there's no domain
# %h - home directory
#
# See /usr/share/doc/dovecot-common/wiki/Variables.txt for full list. Some examples:
#
# mail_location = maildir:~/Maildir
# mail_location = mbox:~/mail:INBOX=/var/mail/%u
# mail_location = mbox:/var/mail/%d/%1n/%n:INDEX=/var/indexes/%d/%1n/%n
#
# <doc/wiki/MailLocation.txt>
#
mail_location = maildir:/var/vmail/%d/%n/Maildir

# If you need to set multiple mailbox locations or want to change default
# namespace settings, you can do it by defining namespace sections.
#
# You can have private, shared and public namespaces. The only difference
# between them is how Dovecot announces them to client via NAMESPACE
# extension. Shared namespaces are meant for user-owned mailboxes which are
# shared to other users, while public namespaces are for more globally
# accessible mailboxes.
#
# REMEMBER: If you add any namespaces, the default namespace must be added
# explicitly, ie. mail_location does nothing unless you have a namespace
# without a location setting. Default namespace is simply done by having a
# namespace with empty prefix.
#namespace private {
# Hierarchy separator to use. You should use the same separator for all
# namespaces or some clients get confused. '/' is usually a good one.
# The default however depends on the underlying mail storage format.
#separator =

# Prefix required to access this namespace. This needs to be different for
# all namespaces. For example "Public/".
#prefix =

# Physical location of the mailbox. This is in same format as
# mail_location, which is also the default for it.
#location =

# There can be only one INBOX, and this setting defines which namespace
# has it.
#inbox = no

# If namespace is hidden, it's not advertised to clients via NAMESPACE
# extension. You'll most likely also want to set list=no. This is mostly
# useful when converting from another server with different namespaces which
# you want to deprecate but still keep working. For example you can create
# hidden namespaces with prefixes "~/mail/", "~%u/mail/" and "mail/".
#hidden = yes

# Show the mailboxes under this namespace with LIST command. This makes the
# namespace visible for clients that don't support NAMESPACE extension.
#list = yes

# Namespace handles its own subscriptions. If set to "no", the parent
# namespace handles them (empty prefix should always have this as "yes")
#subscriptions = yes
#}

# System user and group used to access mails. If you use multiple, userdb
# can override these by returning uid or gid fields. You can use either numbers
# or names. <doc/wiki/UserIds>
#mail_uid =
#mail_gid =

# Group to enable temporarily for privileged operations. Currently this is
# used only with INBOX when either its initial creation or dotlocking fails.
# Typically this is set to "mail" to give access to /var/mail.
#mail_privileged_group =
mail_privileged_group = mail

# Grant access to these supplementary groups for mail processes. Typically
# these are used to set up access to shared mailboxes. Note that it may be
# dangerous to set these if users can create symlinks (e.g. if "mail" group is
# set here, ln -s /var/mail ~/mail/var could allow a user to delete others'
# mailboxes, or ln -s /secret/shared/box ~/mail/mybox would allow reading it).
#mail_access_groups =

# Allow full filesystem access to clients. There's no access checks other than
# what the operating system does for the active UID/GID. It works with both
# maildir and mboxes, allowing you to prefix mailboxes names with eg. /path/
# or ~user/.
#mail_full_filesystem_access = no

##
## Mail processes
##

# Enable mail process debugging. This can help you figure out why Dovecot
# isn't finding your mails.
mail_debug = yes

# Log prefix for mail processes.
# See /usr/share/doc/dovecot-common/wiki/Variables.txt for list of
# possible variables you can use.
#mail_log_prefix = "%Us(%u): "

# Max. number of lines a mail process is allowed to log per second before it's
# throttled. 0 means unlimited. Typically there's no need to change this
# unless you're using mail_log plugin, which may log a lot. This setting is
# ignored while mail_debug=yes to avoid pointless throttling.
#mail_log_max_lines_per_sec = 10

# Don't use mmap() at all. This is required if you store indexes to shared
# filesystems (NFS or clustered filesystem).
#mmap_disable = no

# Rely on O_EXCL to work when creating dotlock files. NFS supports O_EXCL
# since version 3, so this should be safe to use nowadays by default.
#dotlock_use_excl = yes

# Don't use fsync() or fdatasync() calls. This makes the performance better
# at the cost of potential data loss if the server (or the file server)
# goes down.
#fsync_disable = no

# Mail storage exists in NFS. Set this to yes to make Dovecot flush NFS caches
# whenever needed. If you're using only a single mail server this isn't needed.
#mail_nfs_storage = no
# Mail index files also exist in NFS. Setting this to yes requires
# mmap_disable=yes and fsync_disable=no.
#mail_nfs_index = no

# Locking method for index files. Alternatives are fcntl, flock and dotlock.
# Dotlocking uses some tricks which may create more disk I/O than other locking
# methods. NFS users: flock doesn't work, remember to change mmap_disable.
#lock_method = fcntl

# Drop all privileges before exec()ing the mail process. This is mostly
# meant for debugging, otherwise you don't get core dumps. It could be a small
# security risk if you use single UID for multiple users, as the users could
# ptrace() each others processes then.
#mail_drop_priv_before_exec = no

# Show more verbose process titles (in ps). Currently shows user name and
# IP address. Useful for seeing who are actually using the IMAP processes
# (eg. shared mailboxes or if same uid is used for multiple accounts).
#verbose_proctitle = no

# Valid UID range for users, defaults to 500 and above. This is mostly
# to make sure that users can't log in as daemons or other system users.
# Note that denying root logins is hardcoded to dovecot binary and can't
# be done even if first_valid_uid is set to 0.
first_valid_uid = 5000
last_valid_uid = 5000

# Valid GID range for users, defaults to non-root/wheel. Users having
# non-valid GID as primary group ID aren't allowed to log in. If user
# belongs to supplementary groups with non-valid GIDs, those groups are
# not set.
first_valid_gid = 8
last_valid_gid = 8

# Maximum number of running mail processes. When this limit is reached,
# new users aren't allowed to log in.
#max_mail_processes = 512

# Set max. process size in megabytes. Most of the memory goes to mmap()ing
# files, so it shouldn't harm much even if this limit is set pretty high.
#mail_process_size = 256

# Maximum allowed length for mail keyword name. It's only forced when trying
# to create new keywords.
#mail_max_keyword_length = 50

# ':' separated list of directories under which chrooting is allowed for mail
# processes (ie. /var/mail will allow chrooting to /var/mail/foo/bar too).
# This setting doesn't affect login_chroot, mail_chroot or auth chroot
# settings.
# WARNING: Never add directories here which local users can modify, that
# may lead to root exploit. Usually this should be done only if you don't
# allow shell access for users. <doc/wiki/Chrooting.txt>
#valid_chroot_dirs =

# Default chroot directory for mail processes. This can be overridden for
# specific users in user database by giving /./ in user's home directory
# (eg. /home/./user chroots into /home). Note that usually there is no real
# need to do chrooting, Dovecot doesn't allow users to access files outside
# their mail directory anyway. If your home directories are prefixed with
# the chroot directory, append "/." to mail_chroot. <doc/wiki/Chrooting.txt>
#mail_chroot =

##
## Mailbox handling optimizations 
##

# The minimum number of mails in a mailbox before updates are done to cache
# file. This allows optimizing Dovecot's behavior to do less disk writes at
# the cost of more disk reads.
#mail_cache_min_mail_count = 0

# When IDLE command is running, mailbox is checked once in a while to see if
# there are any new mails or other changes. This setting defines the minimum
# time in seconds to wait between those checks. Dovecot can also use dnotify,
# inotify and kqueue to find out immediately when changes occur.
#mailbox_idle_check_interval = 30

# Save mails with CR+LF instead of plain LF. This makes sending those mails
# take less CPU, especially with sendfile() syscall with Linux and FreeBSD.
# But it also creates a bit more disk I/O which may just make it slower.
# Also note that if other software reads the mboxes/maildirs, they may handle
# the extra CRs wrong and cause problems.
#mail_save_crlf = no

##
## Maildir-specific settings
##

# By default LIST command returns all entries in maildir beginning with a dot.
# Enabling this option makes Dovecot return only entries which are directories.
# This is done by stat()ing each entry, so it causes more disk I/O.
# (For systems setting struct dirent->d_type, this check is free and it's
# done always regardless of this setting)
#maildir_stat_dirs = no

# When copying a message, do it with hard links whenever possible. This makes
# the performance much better, and it's unlikely to have any side effects.
#maildir_copy_with_hardlinks = yes

# When copying a message, try to preserve the base filename. Only if the
# destination mailbox already contains the same name (ie. the mail is being
# copied there twice), a new name is given. The destination filename check is
# done only by looking at dovecot-uidlist file, so if something outside
# Dovecot does similar filename preserving copies, you may run into problems.
# NOTE: This setting requires maildir_copy_with_hardlinks = yes to work.
#maildir_copy_preserve_filename = no

##
## IMAP specific settings
##

protocol imap {
# Login executable location.
#login_executable = /usr/lib/dovecot/imap-login

# IMAP executable location. Changing this allows you to execute other
# binaries before the imap process is executed.
#
# This would write rawlogs into ~/dovecot.rawlog/ directory:
# mail_executable = /usr/lib/dovecot/rawlog /usr/lib/dovecot/imap
#
# This would attach gdb into the imap process and write backtraces into
# /tmp/gdbhelper.* files:
# mail_executable = /usr/lib/dovecot/gdbhelper /usr/lib/dovecot/imap
#
#mail_executable = /usr/lib/dovecot/imap

# Maximum IMAP command line length in bytes. Some clients generate very long
# command lines with huge mailboxes, so you may need to raise this if you get
# "Too long argument" or "IMAP command line too large" errors often.
#imap_max_line_length = 65536

# Maximum number of IMAP connections allowed for a user from each IP address.
# NOTE: The username is compared case-sensitively.
mail_max_userip_connections = 10

# Support for dynamically loadable plugins. mail_plugins is a space separated
# list of plugins to load.
#mail_plugins =
#mail_plugin_dir = /usr/lib/dovecot/modules/imap

# Send IMAP capabilities in greeting message. This makes it unnecessary for
# clients to request it with CAPABILITY command, so it saves one round-trip.
# Many clients however don't understand it and ask the CAPABILITY anyway.
login_greeting_capability = yes

# IMAP logout format string:
# %i - total number of bytes read from client
# %o - total number of bytes sent to client
#imap_logout_format = bytes=%i/%o

# Override the IMAP CAPABILITY response.
#imap_capability =

# Workarounds for various client bugs:
imap_client_workarounds = outlook-idle delay-newmail tb-extra-mailbox-sep
}

##
## POP3 specific settings
##

protocol pop3 {
# Login executable location.
#login_executable = /usr/lib/dovecot/pop3-login

# POP3 executable location. See IMAP's mail_executable above for examples
# how this could be changed.
#mail_executable = /usr/lib/dovecot/pop3

# Don't try to set mails non-recent or seen with POP3 sessions. This is
# mostly intended to reduce disk I/O. With maildir it doesn't move files
# from new/ to cur/, with mbox it doesn't write Status-header.
#pop3_no_flag_updates = no

# Support LAST command which exists in old POP3 specs, but has been removed
# from new ones. Some clients still wish to use this though. Enabling this
# makes RSET command clear all \Seen flags from messages.
#pop3_enable_last = no

# If mail has X-UIDL header, use it as the mail's UIDL.
#pop3_reuse_xuidl = no

# Keep the mailbox locked for the entire POP3 session.
#pop3_lock_session = no

# POP3 UIDL (unique mail identifier) format to use. You can use following
# variables, along with the variable modifiers described in
# doc/wiki/Variables.txt (e.g. %Uf for the filename in uppercase)
#
# %v - Mailbox's IMAP UIDVALIDITY
# %u - Mail's IMAP UID
# %m - MD5 sum of the mailbox headers in hex (mbox only)
# %f - filename (maildir only)
#
# If you want UIDL compatibility with other POP3 servers, use:
# UW's ipop3d : %08Xv%08Xu
# Courier : %f or %v-%u (both might be used simultaneosly)
# Cyrus (<= 2.1.3) : %u
# Cyrus (>= 2.1.4) : %v.%u
# Dovecot v0.99.x : %v.%u
# tpop3d : %Mf
#
# Note that Outlook 2003 seems to have problems with %v.%u format which was
# Dovecot's default, so if you're building a new server it would be a good
# idea to change this. %08Xu%08Xv should be pretty fail-safe.
#
pop3_uidl_format = %08Xu%08Xv

# POP3 logout format string:
# %i - total number of bytes read from client
# %o - total number of bytes sent to client
# %t - number of TOP commands
# %p - number of bytes sent to client as a result of TOP command
# %r - number of RETR commands
# %b - number of bytes sent to client as a result of RETR command
# %d - number of deleted messages
# %m - number of messages (before deletion)
# %s - mailbox size in bytes (before deletion)
#pop3_logout_format = top=%t/%p, retr=%r/%b, del=%d/%m, size=%s

# Maximum number of POP3 connections allowed for a user from each IP address.
# NOTE: The username is compared case-sensitively.
mail_max_userip_connections = 3

# Support for dynamically loadable plugins. mail_plugins is a space separated
# list of plugins to load.
#mail_plugins =
#mail_plugin_dir = /usr/lib/dovecot/modules/pop3

# Workarounds for various client bugs:
# outlook-no-nuls:
# Outlook and Outlook Express hang if mails contain NUL characters.
# This setting replaces them with 0x80 character.
# oe-ns-eoh:
# Outlook Express and Netscape Mail breaks if end of headers-line is
# missing. This option simply sends it if it's missing.
# The list is space-separated.
pop3_client_workarounds = outlook-no-nuls oe-ns-eoh
}

##
## LDA specific settings
##

protocol lda {
# Address to use when sending rejection mails.
# postmaster_address = postmaster@mobithought.com
postmaster_address = shenoudab@gmail.com

# Hostname to use in various parts of sent mails, eg. in Message-Id.
# Default is the system's real hostname.
#hostname =

# Support for dynamically loadable plugins. mail_plugins is a space separated
# list of plugins to load.
mail_plugins = cmusieve
#mail_plugin_dir = /usr/lib/dovecot/modules/lda

# If user is over quota, return with temporary failure instead of
# bouncing the mail.
quota_full_tempfail = yes

# Format to use for logging mail deliveries. You can use variables:
# %$ - Delivery status message (e.g. "saved to INBOX")
# %m - Message-ID
# %s - Subject
# %f - From address
deliver_log_format = msgid=%m: %$

# Binary to use for sending mails.
#sendmail_path = /usr/lib/sendmail

# Subject: header to use for rejection mails. You can use the same variables
# as for rejection_reason below.
#rejection_subject = Automatically rejected mail

# Human readable error message for rejection mails. You can use variables:
# %n = CRLF, %r = reason, %s = original subject, %t = recipient
rejection_reason = Your message to <%t> was automatically rejected:%n%r

# UNIX socket path to master authentication server to find users.
auth_socket_path = /var/run/dovecot/auth-master
}

##
## Authentication processes
##

# Executable location
#auth_executable = /usr/lib/dovecot/dovecot-auth

# Set max. process size in megabytes.
#auth_process_size = 256

# Authentication cache size in kilobytes. 0 means it's disabled.
# Note that bsdauth, PAM and vpopmail require cache_key to be set for caching
# to be used.
#auth_cache_size = 0
# Time to live in seconds for cached data. After this many seconds the cached
# record is no longer used, *except* if the main database lookup returns
# internal failure. We also try to handle password changes automatically: If
# user's previous authentication was successful, but this one wasn't, the
# cache isn't used. For now this works only with plaintext authentication.
#auth_cache_ttl = 3600
# TTL for negative hits (user not found). 0 disables caching them completely.
#auth_cache_negative_ttl = 3600

# Space separated list of realms for SASL authentication mechanisms that need
# them. You can leave it empty if you don't want to support multiple realms.
# Many clients simply use the first one listed here, so keep the default realm
# first.
#auth_realms =

# Default realm/domain to use if none was specified. This is used for both
# SASL realms and appending @domain to username in plaintext logins.
#auth_default_realm =

# List of allowed characters in username. If the user-given username contains
# a character not listed in here, the login automatically fails. This is just
# an extra check to make sure user can't exploit any potential quote escaping
# vulnerabilities with SQL/LDAP databases. If you want to allow all characters,
# set this value to empty.
auth_username_chars = abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ01234567890.-_@

# Username character translations before it's looked up from databases. The
# value contains series of from -> to characters. For example "#@/@" means
# that '#' and '/' characters are translated to '@'.
#auth_username_translation =

# Username formatting before it's looked up from databases. You can use
# the standard variables here, eg. %Lu would lowercase the username, %n would
# drop away the domain if it was given, or "%n-AT-%d" would change the '@' into
# "-AT-". This translation is done after auth_username_translation changes.
#auth_username_format =

# If you want to allow master users to log in by specifying the master
# username within the normal username string (ie. not using SASL mechanism's
# support for it), you can specify the separator character here. The format
# is then <username><separator><master username>. UW-IMAP uses "*" as the
# separator, so that could be a good choice.
#auth_master_user_separator =

# Username to use for users logging in with ANONYMOUS SASL mechanism
#auth_anonymous_username = anonymous
```

Comment: Whoa, talk about a formatting explosion.  I think SF's formatting engine just went Mt. Krakatoa on my screen...

Comment: You need to use the *code block* to format your config file.

Comment: Please please please reformat that post!

Comment: Ok, fixed it...although the next time I have to change someone's *massive* sh^H^H"formatting", I demand a diaper pail and nose pins.

Comment: Dumping all the relevant config files, and an error message seems kind of an abuse of serverfault to me. Have you investigated this at all yourself? The answer below is quite literally the first hit in google.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know which version of dovecot you use, but have you looked at http://blog.janus.cx/archives/237-dovecot-Fatal-postmaster_address-setting-not-given.html?

If that is not the problem, can you detail your dovecot version?

Comment: Thanks for your help.

I'm using dovecot version 1.1.11

and i have remove all spaces and tabs like:
postmaster_address=postmaster@mobithought.com
but the problem still exists.

and how can i make that postmaster@mobithought.com a valid mail

thanks.